# Hide script code from the user who is running it?

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell which i share it with a 'n' number of people and I want to restrict the user from changing the code of the powershell script.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [signing your script](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SigningPowerShellScripts.aspx%20https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2010/06/17/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-sign-windows-powershell-scripts-with-an-enterprise-windows-pki-part-2-of-2/).

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the ps1 file inside an exe file using [PS2EXE](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PS2EXE-Convert-PowerShell-9e4e07f1).

It does add an extra step to updating the script as you need to generate a new exe file everytime.

Comment: A new version is maintained by another guy [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PS2EXE-GUI-Convert-e7cb69d5). It's not the best way to protect the code as it's not a real EXE but just an encapsulator that acts like a zip file.

Comment: I assumed this isn't a request for real hardening, but rather just to stop a casual end-user from easily changing a value in the script.